# Dynamic generation of Forms in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find or develop some VBA to dynamically generate form fields (labels and textboxes).

The source data is a table on a hidden Excel worksheet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can generate new items in the Forms Controls collection by using the Add method specifying the type of control using its CLSID.

This article [Dynamic Excel Forms using VBA](http://database.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/excel-l/dynamic-excel-forms-using-vba-1101469) has some example code.